# Best practice of using Dynamo table when it needs to be periodically updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

In my use case, I need to periodically update a Dynamo table (like once per day). And considering lots of entries need to be inserted, deleted or modified, I plan to drop the old table and create a new one in this case.

- How could I make the table queryable while I recreate it? Which API shall I use? It's fine that the old table is the target table. So that customer won't experience any outage.
- Is it possible I have something like version number of the table so that I could perform rollback quickly?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest table name with a common suffix (some people use date, others use a version number).

Store the usable DynamoDB table name in a configuration store (if you are not already using one, you could use [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/), [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html), another [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) table, a [Redis cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/) or a third party solution  such as [Consul](https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html)).

Automate the creation and insertion of data into a new DynamoDB table. Then update the config store with the name of the newly created DynamoDB table. Allow enough time to switchover, then remove the previous DynamoDB table.

You could do the final part by using [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to automate the workflow with a [Wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) of a few hours to ensure that nothing is happening, in fact you could even add a Lambda function that would validate whether any traffic is hitting the old DynamoDB.